# Parallax scrolling of multiple background layers in Windows Store App (e.g. Skyscanner app)

Tags: windows-store-apps

The Skyscanner app has an interesting background behaviour: when you scroll your content, it seems that there are multiple layers with different scrolling behaviour which trigger kind of a parallax experience. Has anyone an idea how they might have realized that?

I found that link http://w8isms.blogspot.nl/2012/09/parallax-background-in-xaml-revisited.html

But I am not sure whether that explains what we see in the Skyscanner app because here we have only one background image which scrolls slower than the page content. I am looking for multiple background layers, each of them scolling independently.

Answer (score 0):

The example tou've provided has 2 bg layers. And in the general sense, I do not see why a single bg layer is any different than a 100 bg layers - there is basically a converter applied to the x position if each layer.